# I am not able to get names from a table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to get only the name field from database table but I am not able to do.

```
class City extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }
    function index(){

        $this->load->model('city_m');
        $cities = $this->city_m->get();

        foreach($cities as $c)
        {
            $newn[name] = $c->name;

        }
        echo 'done name: '.$newn.'<hr/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what you getting ?

Comment: Post your model code too, and update question with resulted `array`

Comment: $this->db->select('name');

$query = $this->db->get('mytable'); But cannot say exactly without looking at your model. You better refer https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select 

It is the best framework guide.

Comment: class City extends MY_Controller{} I think you are trying to extend CI_Controller here.

Comment: Post your model as suggested by Narendra Sisodia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all what you have provided within your code its seems you've an error over

1) `$newn[name] = $c->name;` you are passing it into an array in wrong manner

2) `echo 'done name: '.$newn.'<hr/>';` you are calling an array not a variable

So you need to update your code as

```
foreach($cities as $c)
{
    $newn = $c->name;
    echo 'done name: '.$newn.'<hr/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the braces in your sample code does not seem to match.

Put this inside your foreach loop

```
echo 'done name: '.$name.'<hr/>';
```

Also, take note that you cannot echo array variables.

Answer (score 2):

if you want all city name in one array.... then you can use this code.

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('city_m');
    $cities = $this->city_m->get();

    foreach($cities as $c)
    {
        $cityName[] = $c->name;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($cityName);
}
```

If you want to use these city name into your view then you can use this code

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('city_m');
    $cities = $this->city_m->get();

    foreach($cities as $c)
    {
        $data['cityName'][] = $c->name;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data['cityName']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use like below,

```
$model =  $this->load->model('city_m');
$cities = $model->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing an array, try the below:

```
foreach($cities as $c) {
  $newn = $c->name;   
  echo 'done name: '.$newn.'<hr/>';           
}
```